# Seamlessly migrating <experimental/optional> to <optional>

Tags: c++, c++17, optional

From [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060437/1896169), I learned that C++17 will have `__has_include`, which can

> [make] migrating from experimental to std almost seamless

This still leaves the question of how to do it. Doing something like `namespace std { using namespace std::experimental; }` is undefined behaviour, so I came up with this method:

**optional.h** <sup>[demonstration on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08d4d65f71e45c0a)</sup>

```
#pragma once

#if __has_include(<optional>)
#   include <optional>
#   define HAS_STD_OPTIONAL
#elif __has_include(<experimental/optional>)
#   include <experimental/optional>
#   define HAS_STD_EXPERIMENTAL_OPTIONAL
#else
#   error Must have an optional type, either from <optional> or if not supported from <experimental/optional>.
#endif

#if defined HAS_STD_OPTIONAL

namespace opt {
    template<class T>
    using optional = std::optional<T>;
    using bad_optional_access = std::bad_optional_access;
    using nullopt_t = std::nullopt_t;
    using in_place_t = std::in_place_t;

    constexpr auto nullopt = std::nullopt;
    constexpr auto in_place = std::in_place;

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto make_optional(T && value)
    {
        return std::make_optional(std::forward<T>(value));
    }
}

#elif defined HAS_STD_EXPERIMENTAL_OPTIONAL

namespace opt {
    template<class T>
    using optional = std::experimental::optional<T>;
    using bad_optional_access = std::experimental::bad_optional_access;
    using nullopt_t = std::experimental::nullopt_t;
    using in_place_t = std::experimental::in_place_t;

    constexpr auto nullopt = std::experimental::nullopt;
    constexpr auto in_place = std::experimental::in_place;

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto make_optional(T && value)
    {
        return std::experimental::make_optional(std::forward<T>(value));
    }
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A modification of @Jerry's answer:

```
#pragma once

#if __has_include(<optional>)

#   include <optional>
namespace stdx {
  using namespace ::std;
}
#elif __has_include(<experimental/optional>)
#   include <experimental/optional>
namespace stdx {
  using namespace ::std;
  using namespace ::std::experimental;
}

#else
#   error <experimental/optional> and <optional> not found
#endif
```

this has the advantage that the same namespace can be used for all "experimental" features (`stdx`).

So `stdx::optional` and `stdx::variant` both work.

We have to only `using namespace ::std::experimental;` after at least one `<experimental/` header is included, as if it does not exist that is ill formed, and introducing one ourselves also makes the program ill formed.

Comment: Why have `using namespace ::std;` in the second case (with `<experimental/optional>`)? Also, why do you prefix the namespace with `::`? It doesn't seem necessary to me.

Comment: @justin Because I want to minimize differences between cases where `experimental/optional` exists and does not.  Why prefix with `::`?  In case there is a `namespace std::std` or a `std::experimental::std` or whatever: I want to be unambiguous.  Otherwise `using namespace std;` after a `using namespace std;` might use `std::std`, which is unexpected.  We are doing strange mojo, I am going to be paranoid.

Answer (score 10):

Although there are definitely (at times annoying) limitations on what they can do, at first glance it looks like they don't apply here so I'd at least attempt to use a namespace alias:

```
#pragma once

#if __has_include(<optional>)

#   include <optional>
    using namespace opt = std;

#elif __has_include(<experimental/optional>)
#   include <experimental/optional>

    using namespace opt = std::experimental;

#else
#   error Must have an optional type, either from <optional> or if not supported from <experimental/optional>.
#endif
```

Then from that point, you just use: `opt::whatever`, and that maps to either `std::whatever` or `std::experimental::whatever`, as appropriate.

Comment: \*facepalm\*. This is why I need Code Review

Comment: Wouldn't this cause problems if I try to use other experimental types than `std::optional`? It seems a bit weird to do `opt::any`... I guess then the namespace should really be `stdext` or something of that sort.

Comment: @Justin: Yeah, as you can probably guess from how I originally posted this, I started out with `using namespace stdex = ...`, then (partially) switched it to use `opt` as you had in the question. You could perfectly well define both `stdext` (or whatever) and `opt`, and use them as appropriate (even though they're essentially synonymous with each other). Not really sure whether the latter is a good idea or not though.

Comment: `namespace stdx { using namespace ::std; using namespace ::std::experimental; }` would work, no?

Comment: @Yakk That would require that both `std` and `std::experimental` are defined, but I don't see why that wouldn't work: `namespace std { namespace experimental {} } namespace stdx { using namespace std; using namespace std::experimental; }`. Wonder if there are any collisions between `std` and `std::experimental`.

Comment: @Yakk That wouldn't work the way you seem to intend, because it'd simply dump the contents of `namespace ::std` into the global namespace, and not into `stdx`, because the using directive works on the nearest enclosing namespace, which for `std` is always global.

Comment: The line with `using namespace ...` doesn't seem to compile. I think what you mean is: `namespace opt = std;`, without the "using".

Answer (score 5):

Similar to the other answers, but *just* for optional, without bringing in the rest of std::experimental. Incidentally, we use this in a real codebase:

```
#pragma once

#if __has_include(<optional>)

#include <optional>
namespace stdx {
    using std::optional;
    using std::nullopt_t;
    using std::in_place_t;
    using std::bad_optional_access;
    using std::nullopt;
    using std::in_place;
    using std::make_optional;
}

#elif __has_include(<experimental/optional>)

#include <experimental/optional>
namespace stdx {
    using std::experimental::optional;
    using std::experimental::nullopt_t;
    using std::experimental::in_place_t;
    using std::experimental::bad_optional_access;
    using std::experimental::nullopt;
    using std::experimental::in_place;
    using std::experimental::make_optional;
}

#else
    #error "an implementation of optional is required!"
#endif
```